# C# - Capture Output from a Child Window of a new Process

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, visual-c#-express-2010, unreal-development-kit, unrealscript

Okay, im not going to piddle foot around and dance around what im doing.
Straight up, im trying to make a GUI UnrealScript compiler for the Unreal Development Kit in C#. The exact nature is for something bigger, but this is whats happening:

I start a new thread that starts a new process, and set up a streamreader that that has a listener to capture output as it is written to the console window. 
This isn't a problem, except for the fact that when launching `UDK.exe make` it seems to spawn a child console window thats the actual compiler. 
If I `CD` over to my `UDK/Binaries/Win32` directory, and do the command `UDK.exe make >> output.txt` absolutely nothing gets written, but the file is created (and of course the compiler tends to run as well)

I am using (as far as i can tell) threadsafe operations to access my output textbox which I would like to write to as the compiler is running.

Heres my code:

```
public partial class ProjectEditor : Form
{
   delegate void SetTextCallback(string text);

   /*** ... other completely unrealted code ... ***/

   private void Menu_Project_Compile_JustCompile_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        Thread compile = new Thread( 
            new ThreadStart (
                this.Compile
            )
        );
        NewConsoleLine("Starting Compiler New");
        compile.Start();
    }


    ////////

    private void Compile() {
        this.RunWithRedirect(FileMan.getUDK(), " make");
    }

    void RunWithRedirect(string cmdPath, string args = null) {

        var proc = new Process();
        proc.StartInfo.FileName = cmdPath;
        proc.StartInfo.Arguments = args;

        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        proc.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
        proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;

        proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;

        proc.ErrorDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;
        proc.OutputDataReceived += proc_DataReceived;

        proc.Start();

        proc.BeginErrorReadLine();
        proc.BeginOutputReadLine();

        proc.WaitForExit();

    }

    void proc_DataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) {
        NewConsoleLine(e.Data);
    }

    void NewConsoleLine(String text) {
        if (this.OutputConsole.InvokeRequired) {
            SetTextCallback d = new SetTextCallback(NewConsoleLine);
            this.Invoke(d, new object[] { text });
        } else {
            OutputConsole.Text += text + "\n";
        }
    }
}
```

At the moment, when i execute the method to compile, my console gets written the line `Starting Compiler New` and a UDK.exe console window shows up, and hangs there with no output at all for seemingly forever.

Does anyone have any insight as to how to tweak my streamer into capturing the actual output?
I know this is possible because I've seen other IDEs for UnrealScript accomplish this effect (no popup windows, full output written in real time to console window)
I can feel that I am close, but im just NOT quite there yet...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try running `UDK.com make`. That'll run the compiler in the same window you launch it from.

Comment: ....................................... THERES A .COM?!!?! How did I NOT see this! Oh my GAWD yes, you just saved me hours of headache and torment! :D (havent tried it yet, but im sure this is the magic ticket)

Comment: This definitely worked, and I thank you for this immensely. I was starting to get very discouraged